# Can I change framework between mobile app releases

Tags: mobile, nativescript

**Scenario**
I released a mobile phone app built on one framework - e.g Cordova.
Later down the line I decide to rebuild the app in another framework e.g Nativescript.

Would I be able to release the new code for the app (rebuilt in Nativescript) to Google Play and the app store as the same mobile app - so to the end user it would appear as an upgrade (I am aware it would potentially lose any local storage - but this is not an issue).

Comment: You should be able to achieve this on Android so long as you use the same appId and the same keystore credentials you used to upload the Android package.

Comment: Thanks - do you know if the same applies to Apple Store?

Comment: I expect it to be the same, but I can't really speak for it as I've not released anything on the Apple Store.

Comment: Same on iOS - just keep the bundle ID the same and sign with the same certificate / provisioning profile.